# How can I return a value to html tag

Tags: php, html

```
<td> <?php echo $b; ?> </td>
```

I am trying to put the "ad_soyad" value to the table by returning the "ad_soyad" value to the HTML table code above. I have tried return value but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
function func2()
{

    $servername = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "root";
    $password="";
    $database = "customer_list";
    $port = 3306;
    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password, $database, $port);

    $sql = "SELECT ad_soyad,telefon,e_posta,cari_kart_kodu,olusturma_tarihi,guncelleme_tarihi FROM customer_list";
    $result =$con->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            
            echo "ad soyad:".$row["ad_soyad"]." ";
            echo "<br>";
            $aa = $row["ad_soyad"];
            echo "telefon:".$row["telefon"]." ";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "eposta:".$row["e_posta"]." ";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Cari Kart Kodu:".$row["cari_kart_kodu"]." ";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Oluşturma Tarihi:".$row["olusturma_tarihi"]." ";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Guncelleme Tarihi:".$row["guncelleme_tarihi"]." ";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";

            

        }
        ;
    }
```

Comment: require the php file inside the php view file , or create function and return the value

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function, you are just echoing some HTML. Have you tried just calling the function from the markup? `<td> <?php func2(); ?> </td>`

Comment: i just tried it but it wrote the whole function including ad_soyad,telefon,e_posta etc

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you want to echo out? the function is working fine, please add clearly so we can help you :)

Comment: You don't need numerous `echo` calls. Use 1.